# What am I missing in order to create an UIGridLayout in code?

Tags: user-interface, lua, grid, local, roblox

this is a question about creating a UIGridLayout. I know how to do this using the Studio menus, but I am trying to do it with only code. Here is my code:

```
local layout = Instance.new("UIGridLayout")
layout.Name = "UIGridLayout"
layout.Parent = script.Parent
layout.FillDirection = Enum.FillDirection.Horizontal
layout.CellPadding = UDim2.new(0, 100, 0, 5)
layout.CellSize = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 200)
layout.HorizontalAlignment = Enum.HorizontalAlignment.Center
layout.SortOrder = Enum.SortOrder.LayoutOrder
layout.StartCorner = Enum.StartCorner.TopLeft
layout.VerticalAlignment = Enum.VerticalAlignment.Bottom

local teamFrame = Instance.new("Frame")
teamFrame.BackgroundTransparency = 0
teamFrame.LayoutOrder = 0
teamFrame.Parent = script.Parent



local lblTeamTag = Instance.new("TextLabel", teamFrame)
lblTeamTag.TextTransparency = 0
lblTeamTag.TextStrokeTransparency = 0
lblTeamTag.Name = "TeamTag"
lblTeamTag.Text = "Team"
lblTeamTag.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 50) 
lblTeamTag.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)

local lblPoints = Instance.new("TextLabel", teamFrame)
lblPoints.TextStrokeTransparency = 0
lblPoints.BackgroundTransparency = 0
lblPoints.Name = "Points"
lblPoints.Text = "0"
lblPoints.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 150)
lblPoints.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 50)
```

The script where this code sits is a local script child of ScreenGui. I am expecting to see something like this:

[image]

But I got nothing. I know I am close. What am I missing. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you're getting is just the TextLabels not being in the right places, it's because the UIGridLayout has to be inside the frame instead of being inside the same parent of the frame. So if you instance the UIGridLayout after instancing the frame and then making the frame the parent of the UIGridLayout it should work. Here's how it should be done so you can just copy and paste:

```lua
local teamFrame = Instance.new("Frame")
teamFrame.BackgroundTransparency = 0
teamFrame.LayoutOrder = 0
teamFrame.Parent = script.Parent

local layout = Instance.new("UIGridLayout")
layout.Name = "UIGridLayout"
layout.Parent = script.Parent
layout.FillDirection = Enum.FillDirection.Horizontal
layout.CellPadding = UDim2.new(0, 100, 0, 5)
layout.CellSize = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 200)
layout.HorizontalAlignment = Enum.HorizontalAlignment.Center
layout.SortOrder = Enum.SortOrder.LayoutOrder
layout.StartCorner = Enum.StartCorner.TopLeft
layout.VerticalAlignment = Enum.VerticalAlignment.Bottom



local lblTeamTag = Instance.new("TextLabel", teamFrame)
lblTeamTag.TextTransparency = 0
lblTeamTag.TextStrokeTransparency = 0
lblTeamTag.Name = "TeamTag"
lblTeamTag.Text = "Team"
lblTeamTag.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 50) 
lblTeamTag.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 0)

local lblPoints = Instance.new("TextLabel", teamFrame)
lblPoints.TextStrokeTransparency = 0
lblPoints.BackgroundTransparency = 0
lblPoints.Name = "Points"
lblPoints.Text = "0"
lblPoints.Size = UDim2.new(0, 200, 0, 150)
lblPoints.Position = UDim2.new(0, 0, 0, 50)
```